# curve () function with log variable

Tags: r

I want to plot my statistics and visualise the S-curve with curve () command. The problem is that it doesn't work with my log-variable as shown below. What am I doing wrong?

Error message from the last row of code:
Error: unexpected '=' in "curve(predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(log(Befolkning) ="

```
fit = glm(Arbetsloshet_okat ~ log(Befolkning), data=data, family=binomial)
newdat <- data.frame(Befolkning=seq(0,291))
newdat$Arbetsloshet_okat = predict(fit, newdata=newdat, type="response")
plot(Arbetsloshet_okat~log(Befolkning), data=data,xlim=c(7,15),col="red4")
curve(predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(log(Befolkning) = x), **type = "response"), add = TRUE, col= "green4", lwd = 2)**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of curve use lines:

```
plot(Arbetsloshet_okat~log(Befolkning), data=data,col="red4")
lines(newdat$Arbetsloshet_okat~log(newdat$Befolkning), col= "green4", lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: This worked!! There is a line, but the line stops before it reaches my statistics?

Comment: Difficult to know why without data. Change your line `newdat <- data.frame(Befolkning=seq(0,291))` to `newdat <- data.frame(Befolkning=seq(min(data$Befolkning),max(data$Befolkning)))`